# Run a job when a variable is set/unset and it's a merge request

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want a job to run when 2 conditions are met:

1. There has been a merge request on the branch
2. A specific variable is not set

With the latest Gitlab in saas mode, I put this config in my job:

```
  rules:
    - if: ('$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"') && ($DESTROY_ONLY == null)
```

But it's run on a push. Do you see why?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was an incorrect syntax. It should rather be:

```
  rules:
    - if: '($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($DESTROY_ONLY == null)'
```